# DeclarationError: Identifier already declared. when writing in solidity

Tags: remix

> DeclarationError: Identifier already declared near function

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract Timestamp{
   uint start;
   uint end;
   function start() public{
      start = block.timestamp;
   } 
   function end() public {
      end = block.timestamp;
   } 
   function getTimeDif() view public returns(uint) {
      return end - start;
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not declare function name same as variables name because solidity automatic create the getter function of public variables.